# Suggestion About Creating a Web Database Application

Tags: mysql, wordpress, vba

I am new in web developers world. I have created a website (www.formsify.in) on Wordpress all by learning on internet. I know the basics of coding and programming languages, etc. and the interest so I learn quickly. Now my objective is to let users search and download documents (.pdf). The way I dl it now is by uploading the documents in Media and use buttons to navigate to the page which displays documents in a tabular form.

Now, this works if the documents are less in numbers. But I know the number of documents will increase and it will be very difficult for me to deal with uploading them one by one and creating tables all the time. So I thought to create

(1). Database of documents
(2). Uploading interface
(3). User interface

I want suggestions whether I am thinking in the right direction or can there be a better way to accomplish this. And if this is a right way to do

- What database shall I use keeping in mind that I the documents to be stored online so the database should be online.
- How should I go about creating the uploading interface keeping in mind that I am not a code-geek.
- How shall I be going to design the user interface.

I know these are very wide and open questions. Also because stalwarts here will give me a non-commercial, non-biased view. I just need directions. I was able to create a decent website (as per my standards) when I didn't know much the only thing drove me to do that was that I was hellbent. I will be thankful for any suggestions.

Thanks,
.farhan

Comment: You can use php to save the files in a folder on your server. Thats the simpliest

Answer (score 1):

So,  basically,  you should have 2  tables:

User
Upload

User hold an ID and whatever information you want to have on the user and the upload table holds a unique ID,  a user ID (of the uploader) and a path to the document

This way,  you can select the uploads (add filters if needed) and you can construct the tables and views using the database results

The uploading is a simple html form that will send the file to a php script that will upload the file to a folder (rename it as well) and insert the new path in the dB.

The user interface just needs to hold a bit of html, with a form element and an action to a php script to handle the upload.

You can find the upload script on w3schools,  just add the mysql insert to the database.